# ¿Qué palabra se puede utilizar para describir a una persona con un egoísmo muy desmesurado?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Existe alguna palabra para describir a una persona con un egoísmo tan desmesurado al punto que no le importa la vida de los demás?

Comment: Como siempre, ¿qué se te ocurre? ¿Podrías dar ejemplos donde este adjetivo pueda usarse?

Comment: ¿Rechazaste *egoísta* por alguna razón?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo mejor (lo único) que se me ocurre es [**ególatra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ER392SG)

> 1. adj. Que profesa la egolatría. U. t. c. s.

siendo [**egolatría**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ER9ByHj):

> Del gr. *ἐγώ egṓ* o lat. *ego* 'yo' y -latría.
>   1. f. Culto, adoración o amor excesivo de sí mismo.

Answer (score 3):

Os dejo un sinónimo poco conocido de *egoísta* que acabo de encontrar: ***[filautero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hu5Lege)***. Proviene de ***[filaucía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hu5KBsI)***, del griego *φιλαυτία philautía* 'egoísmo'.

También tienes ***[egocéntrico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EQqhi27)*** y una un tanto cómica: ***[rompenecios](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Wf7moVj)***.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor es **ególatra**, ya mencionado por @Leonardo en su respuesta.

Como complemento agrego el concepto de **egópata**, que es específico de la psicología:

> **Egopatía**
>
> (1) Conducta agresiva, violenta, que tiene como origen un fuerte egocentrismo que le lleva al desprecio de los demás ([fuente](https://psiquiatria.com/glosario/egopatia)).
>
> (2) Actitud agresiva y hostil respecto a los demás debida a una sobrevaloración de sí. Es frecuente en las personalidades psicopáticas (v. psicopatía) que, mediante la hostilidad y la agresión, se reafirman en su propia fuerza y virilidad ([fuente](http://consulta-psicologica.com/diccionario-de-psicologia/314-egopatia.html)).

Y propongo también el concepto político de **[estirnerista](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarquismo_ego%C3%ADsta)**, usado de forma bastante imprecisa, generalmente con el significado de "violentista" o "terrorista".